# How can I plot more than 20 figures from jupyter notebook to html?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

I'm finding a solution to output the results from jupyter notebook to html. I downloaded data results from jupyter notebook and ran `jupyter nbconvert --to html mynotebook.ipynb` command in the cli.

The html version shows that "More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).

I want to show all the figures more than 20. How can I do that? Can anyone help me?